# Have text input slide over to reveal new text input on enter? Then slide back?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Alright right now I have 1 form and 1 text input field:

```
echo '<form class="changePassForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
echo '<input class = "passwordText" type="password" placeholder="Change Password" name="passwordText">';
echo '<input class = "oldPass" type="password" placeholder="Enter Old Password" name="oldPass">';
echo '</form>';
```

When the user presses enter on the passwordText input, the text entered is passed in a variable to a php file:

```
$(".passwordText").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      var pass = $(this).val();
        //var pass = document.getElementById("p2");
    $.ajax({
        url: "../php/passwordchange.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: 'passwordText=' + pass, // data sent to php file
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
            console.log(data);

        }});    
     console.log("WORKS!!");   
    }
});
```

When this happens, I need the .passwordText input field to slide over and become hidden (not able to interacted with) so I can get the value from a second text input. I do not know how to do this as I am a beginner with javascript.

The following is my CSS for reference:

```
.changePassForm input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.changePassForm input:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.changePassForm input:focus {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  color: #53e3a6;
}
.changePassForm button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #53e3a6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
.changePassForm button:hover {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}
```

How can I move the first input over to get the value from a 2nd text input?

Comment: Where is your second input?  After your first (under it on the next line)?  And where do you want the first input to slide to?  What about just disabling the field?

Comment: Yes..Indeed where is your 2nd `input` ?

Comment: Sorry; I have updated the first block of code. I just need the 2nd input to slide over/fade into the 1st. This is for a client so I just need it to look good/have some sort of sliding function. How exactly would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do that in your AJAX success.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "../php/passwordchange.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: 'passwordText=' + pass, // data sent to php file
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            //HERE'S THE PLACE TO DO IT.
            $('.passwordText').slideUp(500)
        }
    });
```

What the code above does is "tell" `passwordText` to hide itself in a 500 millisecond (or half a second) timeframe.

I'm also assuming that when your php executes, it returns a successful response.
You might want to also execute something else should the script return a failed response.

You might wanna have a look at [JSEND](https://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend) for how to structure your JSON responses.

Comment: How I enable and disable my 2nd input via ajax?